# Spacing Bootstrap v5.1.1 vs 4.0.0

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, padding, bootstrap-5

I have two pages, one running with Bootstrap v5.1.1 and one on 4.0.0 and I noticed some changes in the spacing.

### Bootstrap v5.1.1:

```css
.topspacer {
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.righticon {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Bootstrap 5 | Home</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-warning">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 5</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="https://mood-tracker.ch/main.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="settings.php">Settings</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="nrew.php">New Entry</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="report.php">Report</a></li></ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="login.php?logout=1">Logout</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="topspacer"></div>
<main role="main">
    <div class="container">
    
                <div class="list-group">
                
                    <a href="settings.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Settings</a>
                    <a href="new.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">New Entry</a>
                    <a href="report.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">View report</a>
                </div>



</div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Notice how there is now spacing between the edge of the page and the Navbar menu. However if I run the same code with Bootstrap 4.0.0 there is:

### Bootstrap v4.0.0:

```css
.topspacer {
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.righticon {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <title>Bootstrap 4 | Home</title>
        
        </head>
        <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-warning">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 4</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="https://mood-tracker.ch/main.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="settings.php">Settings</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="nrew.php">New Entry</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="report.php">Report</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="login.php?logout=1">Logout</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="topspacer"></div>
    <main role="main">
        <div class="container">
        
                    <div class="list-group">
                    
                        <a href="settings.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Settings</a>
                        <a href="new.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">New Entry</a>
                        <a href="report.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">View report</a>
                    </div>



    </div>
        </main>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Also the list items are bigger with more space. I saw that there were some changes regarding left/right assignment (for example in Navbar) but I could not find a change. Could you point me in the right direction to achieve the same layout as in my bootstrap 4 example? Thanks!

Comment: Please be aware, that Bootstrap uses [SemVer](https://semver.org/). This means, that changes in a major update (4 -> 5) can (and probably will) come with backwards-incompatible changes.

Comment: Yes there are [many changes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#navbars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the exact same layout/spacing is likely not to be possible if those are given by the style changes that can happen between major versions.

The first thing when you encounter such problems is to check [Migrating to v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#navbars), if there is something mentioned about that.

For [Navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#navbars) you have:

> Navbars
> Breaking Navbars now require a container within (to drastically simplify spacing requirements and CSS required).

So you need to add `<div class="container-fluid">` as container in your `<nav>`.

About the spacing this is mentioned in [Components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#components):

> Components
> Unified padding values for alerts, breadcrumbs, cards, dropdowns, list groups, modals, popovers, and tooltips to be based on our `$spacer` variable. See [#30564](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30564).

And `active` should be applied to the `nav-link` and not `nav-item` (`<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"`), but that was also already the case for v4.

```css
.topspacer {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.righticon {
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Bootstrap 5 | Home</title>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-warning">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 5</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="https://mood-tracker.ch/main.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="nrew.php">New Entry</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="report.php">Report</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="login.php?logout=1">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="topspacer"></div>
  <main role="main">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="settings.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Settings</a>
        <a href="new.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">New Entry</a>
        <a href="report.php" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">View report</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Unrelated to your question but `clear: both` and `float: right` is now days most of the time an indication that you do something wrong:

```
.righticon {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the migration part. I don't really care about the spacing in the list entry, thought it may be related as this is different too. Regarding the CSS, I've just copied the file of the old project and am currently not using those classes.